# Problems figuring out weekly scheduling and hours past midnight

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

This is a screenshot of what I have

[image]

What I'm trying to do is have the hours for each individual person posted as shown or a way that the hours can be posted like this and then have the total amount of hours at the end.

The problem I'm having is how to get excel to realize that some employees are working past 12 am in the morning. I keep having the number come out to be negative. 
What would the formula I need be? or do I need to alter my chart? And if I do need to alter the chart what would I need to do and what would the formula need to be after?

Answer (score 0):

To figure total hours when the shift crosses midnight:

Assume start time is `H5` and the cell is formatted with a TIME format.
Assume end time is `I5` and the cell is formatted with a TIME format.

then for J5 use this formula: `=IF(I5-H5<0,HOUR((I5+1)-H5),HOUR(I5-H5))` and give this cell a GENERAL or DECIMAL cell format.

Basically the logic in use is:
IF the result is negative (i.e. the shift crossed midnight),
THEN add +1 (day, i.e. 24 hours) to the end time before subtracting start time,
ELSE end time - start time.
(Why you add +1 as opposed to 24 or something else is manifested with the way excel stores time values internally, and the explanation is really outside the scope of this answer.)

You will probably want to use a calculation area somewhere less visible to calculate hours for each shift, or use hidden columns, then add those across and bring the number back to your total.

Comment: When I do that format it tells me that there is too many variables.

Comment: I cooked that up in excel 2013 and pasted it, I'm not sure why it doesn't work in Excel 2007 I would think that it should, but as of a week ago I no longer have an install of 2007 to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to store everything as date+time (complete specification of the date and time as a single number).  The function NOW does this automatically, but only for the current time.  You can create the entry by adding the DATE plus TIME (the date is stored as a sequential integer representing the number of days since a reference date; the time is stored as a decimal fraction of a day).  You can use functions or incorporate the math in a formula to store the date+time value.

Excel time and date functions work from that representation.  Normal Excel date/time math will then work correctly.  To customize how the stored value is displayed, use the built-in date and time format functions.  In most cases, it will ignore portions of the date+time value that are not relevant to the display format.

Comment: Add the date before the time so it is mm/dd/yyyy [h]:mm format to each day and I'm still not getting the correct total of hours for the week. For instance I have
1/1/2014 12:00 1/1/2014 20:00
1/2/2014 0:00 1/2/2014 0:00
1/3/2014 0:00 1/3/2014 0:00
1/4/2014 12:00 1/4/2014 20:00
1/5/2014 18:00 1/6/2014 2:00
1/6/2014 18:00 1/7/2014 2:00
1/7/2014 18:00 1/8/2014 2:00
With a total amount of hours being 16:00

Comment: Not sure how you concatenated date and time.  It is not just a matter of selecting a format that displays date and time, you need the cell to contain the sum of the date and time for each point.  Assuming that what is stored is correct, you should have a series of start and end times.  Subtract the start time from the end time to get the elapsed time and add those up.