# Calculate hours for time sheet (difference between time, possibly passing midnight)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to help a friend with making him a simple excel template for filling out a time sheet, unfortunately it turned out much harder than i expected a simple time-calculation to be.

What i need is to calculate the time difference between two time fields. So far it's easy but unfortunately it's a night job that regularly passes midnight and then excel simple doesn't get any calculations right without falling back to full date+time fields stuff.

So right now i do this:

```
=IF(C8>B8; C8-B8; TIMEVALUE("23:59")+TIMEVALUE("00:01")-B8+C8)
```

Given the start hour is in B8, and the end time is in C8.

I can't believe there is no easier way of doing it with this hack.

Also the calculation fails for empty values (empty sheet!) displaying `#VALUE!` which i cant't seem to solve. No statement like `IF(NOT(ISBLANK(x));...)` or other checks seem to catch the empty field before doing the calculation.

Comment: See this answer: [Problems figuring out weekly scheduling and hours past midnight](http://superuser.com/a/808506)

Comment: Great, simple solution by barry houdini: http://superuser.com/a/940439/364367

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
=IF(OR(C8="",B8=""),"",IF(C8>=B8,C8-B8,1+C8-B8))
```

*(naturally using the **;** rather than the **,**)*